# Can anyone help me with sorting out my terminal

Tags: python

I am not allowed to submit any photos yet so I will copy and paste what my terminal is saying - it is very messy and I am 100% sure it is not supposed to look the way it does.

```
    >source /opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
    /Users/janwidyma/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
    /Users/janwidyma/.zprofile:7: command not found: pyenv
    /Users/janwidyma/.zprofile:8: command not found: pyenv
    /Users/janwidyma/.zprofile:9: command not found: pyenv
    /Users/janwidyma/.zprofile:10: no such file or directory:/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
    /Users/janwidyma/.zshrc:1: command not found: pyenv
    /Users/janwidyma/.zshrc:2: command not found: pyenv
    janwidyma@Jans-MacBook-Pro Data Science % source /opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
    (base) janwidyma@Jans-MacBook-Pro Data Science % conda activate base
    (base) janwidyma@Jans-MacBook-Pro Data Science %
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do? When you say you are sure it does not look the way it is supposed to look, what is your expectation?

Comment: *I am not allowed to submit any photos yet so I will copy and paste what my terminal is saying* you did the right thing

Comment: Well what’s with all this pyenv command not found stuff and why is there no file found for the homebrew is there a way I can delete everything that has been installed and just start from fresh